# Assinging Single Value to Multiple Index in Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi am having around 50 array values. In which a common value will be placed for most of the indexes for example,

```
var options = {
        'o' : 'blue',
        'a' : 'blue',
        's' : 'blue',
        'n' : 'blue',
        'c' : 'blue',
        'r' : 'red',
        'w' : 'orange',
        'm' : 'green',
        'f' : 'green'
    };
```

Is there any way to simplify like, o | a | s | n = blue ?

Comment: this look like some language like php not javascript

Comment: Yes am sorry, Its been updated.

Answer (score -1):

Make a function that does that, the invokation should look like

```
setSameValueMultipleIndicies(['o','a','s','n'],'blue',options);
```